# What's the Javascript equivalent to SessionVariable in Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, powershell

I have a login script in Powershell that does this:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest "https://example.com" -Method Post -Body @{
                        user   = $user
                        password   = $password
                        rememberMe = $true
                     } -SessionVariable "mySession" -UseBasicParsing
```

I have the following in TypeScript:

```
const bodyData = { user, password, rememberMe }
    
const res = await fetch(authorizationUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyData)
    });
```

What is "SessionVariable"? How do I make my Javascript call look like that? I can't tell if SessionVariable is a cookie on the response, something in the header or something that goes in the request.

Thanks!

Edit: Not answering my own question but it appears that SessionVariable does a lot of things, but importantly stores the cookies. It also looks like the original code (not shown) relies on a null check for SessionVariable though it can be initialized without the correct authorization cookies. In any case if anyone can confirm that's all it does and that just grabbing the cookies is the "Javascript/Typescript way" of doing things let me know!

Comment: The session variable is a [WebRequestSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.webrequestsession?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) object. You already said yourself it does a lot of things. So you should give an example of what you do with it in PowerShell.